# Scalar value that is unique for a matrix

Tags: linear-algebra

I have a computational problem that involves trying to find duplicates among 50,000 or so n x 3 matrices, where n is typically around 100. I'm doing this in MatLab in case that is relevant! I'd like a scalar value that can be assigned to each matrix that will be unique to that matrix, so I can sort that scalar value and pair them up easily without resorting to computationally expensive loops. Does such a thing exist?

Thanks!

Comment: Can you try lexicographic ordering the matrices?

Comment: What datatype is used by these $n \times 3$ matrices?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use a hash function.  Fix some random $n \times 3$ matrix $H$, and let the hash function take matrix $A$ to $\sum_{i,j} A_{ij} H_{ij}$ (in Matlab, sum(sum(H .* A))).  The hash values are not necessarily unique, but the probability of duplication is extremely low.

Comment: Thanks Robert, I was thinking along the same lines but the matrices don't have particularly random values - so with this amount of matrices there is maybe a small possibility of duplication. I ended up using an MD5 Hash of each matrix, so not really a mathematical solution but it works!

Answer (score 0):

If instead of matrix of size $n \times 3$ you view each matrix as vector with $3n$ components you can probably use the [lexicographic order](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lexicographical_order) to sort the matrices and find a duplicate in time $ln(m)$ after they have been sorted ($m$ is the number of matrices).

Comment: Could you elaborate?

Comment: You envision a sorted array of structures (matrices).  My suggestion is the maintenance of an array of such arrays, with the outer index $n$ corresponding to matrix size.  After all duplicate matrices will have the same size.  Since $n$ is known, the depth of binary search is reduced by such pigeonholing of the matrices.

Comment: Ah ok, I was actually suggesting a general algorithm, not an implementation. I think the implementation itself wasn't specifically the point of the question.

Comment: Nor am I suggesting an implementation so much as an algorithm (sorting first by length, known at outset of search, and then by lexicographic order within length).